# Choppy playback Kodi on Raspbian RPI2

Tags: raspbian, video, kodi, omxplayer, osmc

I'm trying to setup Kodi on Raspbian to work as good as OSMC distribution.
I have problem with video playback on default configuration. (no video, only sound) When I turn off hardware acceleration, video works, but it's quite choppy. I don't know what I should do. I was looking for some advices, but nothing worked so far.

Why I want to use Raspbian rather than OSMC system? Because I need to use gpio and webserver.

I'm using class 10, 16gb microSD card, and Raspberry Pi 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I increased gpu_mem from 160/192 (as I found earlier in internet) to 256mb, now it works fine.