# Kodi on Raspbian vs. Kodi on OpenELEC

Tags: raspbian, kodi, openelec

I had Kodi on installed on my Raspbian and some videos didn't work.

I read OpenELEC is optimized for Kodi and indeed, these videos work fine on this distribution.

What are the differences between Raspbian/Kodi and Openelec/Kodi? Why is the behavior different?

Comment: I believe openelec uses a different video player than the default install of kodi through raspbian.

Comment: This question makes no sense in its current form. You're looking for the difference between Raspbian and Kodi - Raspbian is an operating system and Kodi is a software application. It's equivalent to asking what the difference is between Windows and Word. Can you edit the question to indicate which things you're trying to compare?

Comment: My question is edited.

Comment: FYI, actual version of Kodi in Raspbian is `15.2-2`, while the latest version announced on kodi.tv is `17.1-RC1`. Not sure which version is shipped with OpenELEC.

Comment: Also, the answer to [this question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32957/choppy-playback-kodi-on-raspbian-rpi2) suggests that you want to set `gpu_mem` to at least 256Mb, and enable hardware acceleration in Kodi.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I tried with the same version on the two OS of course :)

Comment: I'll try to increase the gpu mem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [following thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=105851) on the RPi forums discusses some differences between OpenELEC+Kodi and Raspbian+Kodi.

According to that discussion, a key difference is the [memory split](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=58245) in Raspbian. Essentially, this determines how much of your RAM is available for running programs and how much is used by the GPU. If you allocate more RAM to the GPU, your Pi can perform more intensive graphics processing.

I suspect (but am not 100% sure) that to get Raspbian+Kodi working more effectively you'd have to adjust this memory split in order for the GPU to run Kodi at a decent speed. Although you'd probably be better off just running OpenELEC from one SD card and installing Raspbian on a second and switch between the two when you want to watch media or play with an OS respectively.

Comment: Hope that helps the videos run at a more acceptable pace!

Comment: it helps also if you need to hack things , i had trouble make the PITFT work without raspbian .
Many dependecies problems are solve this way